# Can a wand choose two people?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

It is possible for a wizard to be chosen by two wands, this makes me wonder if the reverse is true.  **Can two or more persons having similar qualities be CHOSEN by a single wand**? Moreover, is it necessary that a wizard would be chosen by a wand at all? What if the wandmaker hasn't created that particular wand by that time that would choose him.

Update:

If the wandmaker makes a wand specifically for a child, how can he be sure that the wand would choose him/her at all. At such a young age, how can a wandmaker make an idea about the child's specific qualities and temperament?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "child"? We know that 11 is the youngest age that a witch or wizard gets their first wand in the typical tradition -- are you asking about children younger than 11? Or, say, 11 to 13? (Personally, I would not consider a 13-year-old a child; he/she would be an adolescent). Anyway, if you could clarify, that would be great! :)

Comment: For the second question, see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24349/4918 "Is every wizard buying a wand from Ollivander chosen by a wand?"

Answer (score 3):

When a wand chooses the wizard - it does not mean that the wand can be used only by that wizard. It means that both the wand's ability and the wizard's ability are at their maximum when the wizard uses the wand. We can clearly see that Harry uses Hermione's, then Draco's wand in the Deathly Hallows. When Hermione's wand also works for him - he feels most comfortable with Draco's wand as that wand had switched its allegiance.

> Harry:  “A person can still use a wand that hasn’t chosen them, though?”
>
> Ollivander: “Oh yes, if you are any wizard at all you will be able to channel your magic through almost any instrument. The best results, however, must always come where there is the strongest affinity between wizard and wand. These connections are complex. An initial attraction, and then a mutual quest for experience, the wand learning from the wizard, the wizard from the wand.”

---

> Can a wizard be chosen by two wands?

Edited: In the Sorcerer's stone - Ollivander tells Harry:

> "You have your mother's eyes. It seems only yesterday she was in here herself, buying her first wand."

-- Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, CHapter 5: Diagon Alley.

Note that he says her FIRST wand. That indicates Lily had more than one - and she had come to Ollivander more than once. SO yes - I think a wizard can be chosen by more than one wand - since people who have broken their wands have had them replaced; people who win the Elder wand also have their allegiances changed from their previous wand. According to Ollivander in the Deathly Hallows - this is true of all wands which are won.

> Ollivander: “Perhaps not. If you took it –”
>
> Harry: “—I did – ”
>
> Ollivander: “—then it may be yours. Of course, the manner of taking
>   matters. Much also depends upon the wand itself.In general, however,
>   where a wand has been won, its allegiance will change.”

---

> Can 2 or more persons be chosen by a single wand?

Again - I think this should be possible - given the fact that Harry, Draco and Voldemort were able to use multiple wands. If they have similar qualities - then the wand maybe able to perform reasonably well. But if they are different in nature - maybe the wand will not perform to its fullest capability. Furthermore - if there was a chance that wands need to be custom made for a wizard - I think wand makers will operate more like tailors than like clothing outlets! It seems unlikely that they will store multiple wands - if the wands did not have the ability to choose more than 1 person in the world.

> What if the wandmaker hasn't created that particular wand by that time that would choose him?

I remember Ollivander taking Harry's measurements when searching for a wand. I also remember Ollivander making a wand specially for Luna in the Deathly Hallows. So my inference is - the wand maker will make a wand specially for the person in question. What that depends on is difficult to say - since at age 11 - Ollivander would have had no idea about Harry's qualities or temperament.

> If the wandmaker makes a wand specifically for a child, how can he be sure that the wand would choose him/her at all?

I don't think there is any support for a wand having been made specifically for a child. Ollivander made a wand specifically for Luna in the Deathly Hallows - but since he spent a lot of time with her in the Malfoy Mansion and in Shell Cottage - he has a pretty clear idea about her qualities and temperament.

According to Ollivander - the wand and the wizard are connected by a complex connection - starting with initial attraction and then a mutual quest for experience - learning from one another. So - if a child's nature is known - which should be the case since the wand is being made for the child - it is highly possible that even though the child may not be able to exploit the full power of the wand - they would eventually grow - learning from each other. Of course - since there is no support of such a wand ever being made - I can only guess at this point.

Comment: No offence but Draco, Hermione and Voldemort were not chosen by the wands they just used those wand. Elder wand, is an special case, so we may leave that out..Lastly..please add conon in support of your views,,

Comment: In the Deathly Hallows - when Ron asks about the wand he took from Pettigrew, Ollivander says "Yes, if you won it, it is more likely to do your bidding, and do it well, than another wand.” So - whether a wand is bought or is won - it is true that all wands can change their master. And in this case - this was Ron's 3rd wand - first one passed from Charlie (which may not have chosen Ron exactly), second was the unicorn hair wand bought in PoA and finally Pettigrew's wand which was won. This wasn't the elder wand so I think this is a fair enough supporting quote.

Comment: There is an enormous amount of speculation in this answer. I enjoy speculating on HP topics too; at SE we are looking for factual answers, not theories on, say, whether a wand can be made for a child (HP canon truly does not address this, unless it's on Pottermore) or unattributed canon quotes (the answering user allows readers to believe that he/she is the original author of the words in question). I want to know what you *know*, not what you infer. Answers built on strong canon inference -- like when one fits complicated, related pieces of a puzzle together -- are, of course, fine.

Comment: @Slytherincess I addressed the original question to the best of my knowledge. But since some questions are not addressed in any canon - I think a bit of speculation is allowed. Of course - you can edit the answer if I've misquoted something.

Comment: @mustard, I am asking about the **choosing of wand** at the age of eleven not mastering the wand in some way.

Comment: @mustard -- I don't personally think it's my place to edit your post to improve content. If you want it to be good, do it yourself. I believe you'll be more satisfied with the end result. There is a *huge* difference between misquoting something (making an error in the quote, but attributing) and failing to attribute. The latter could be construed as plagiarism. That's very serious and it's your responsibility to ensure that doesn't happen, certainly not mine. Please *at least consider* our suggestions. Sorry to say, but -1 for excessive speculation and a lack of attribution of a canon quote.

Answer (score 3):

A wand chooses its wizard, but that does not mean it can only be used exclusively for that wizard. For example, Voldemort used Lucius Malfoy's wand in DH because he knew his wand wouldn't work against Harry's in an attempt to kill, and Harry used Hermione's wand when his broke. It does not mean, however, that the wand will cooperate very well with any wizard but its master.

A wand can be mastered by another wizard if it is taken by force in battle, as seen in DH when Hermione gets Bellatrix Lestrange's wand while escaping Malfoy Manor before Voldemort arrives. On the other hand, if the wand wasn't taken by force, it could act as it would in Ollivander's when First-Years are getting their wands, like the blackthorn wand Ron had taken from a Snatcher in DH and gave it to Harry. When Harry attempted a simple *Engorgio* spell on a small fire, it over grew, because Harry was not the master of that wand.